# Woocommerce: How to use get_term_by in functions.php : Lookup Product Category ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**When I run the standard Woocommerce Product Import**

- If a meta field in my import spreadsheet indicates that a Product Item must be hidden

  - I set the catalog_visibility to hidden
  - I need to lookup the ID for a special Product Category

    - and append that to that Item's Product Categories

*My Category Name:* Not for Web Sale

*My Category Slug:* not_for_web_sale

So I am calling this in functions.php

```
if($cat_term_object = get_term_by('slug','not_for_web_sale','product_cat')) {
    $cat_term_id = $cat_term_object->term_id;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I am not getting any return value

**WHAT I HAVE FOUND**

This post tells me that:

> This is probably happening because the taxonomy you're trying to query is registered yet. Eg. The WordPress environment is loaded when a theme's functions.php file loads, but many plugins/themes/core functions don't register taxonomies until later.

And it suggests:

> Try hooking into init with a really high priority number and running the get_term_by function. Like so:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse27111_tester', 999 );
function wpse27111_tester()
{
    $term = get_term_by('slug', 'some-term', 'some-taxonomy');
    var_dump($term);
}
```

**WHERE I AM STUCK**

Although I basically understand the explanation of the problem w.r.t. the Woocommerce taxonomy ...
... I am not grasping how to apply that to my needs.

Advice or guidance would be most welcome.

( Unfortunately my rep on that particular stackexchange is too low to comment )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

So what I needed to do in functions.php was

- make my own custom function
- call the get_term_by() from inside my custom function
- add_action with a lower priority number = higher execution priority

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_not_for_sale_category_id', 10 );
function get_not_for_sale_category_id() {
   if ( $cat_term_object = get_term_by('slug','not_for_web_sale','product_cat') ) {
      $cat_term_id_value = $cat_term_object->term_id;
   } else {
      $cat_term_id_value = 1010101;
   }
   return $cat_term_id_value;
```

Then in my import function, I call like this

```
$cat_term_id = get_not_for_sale_category_id();
```

---

**EDIT**

I've hooked it into a more appropriate place.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_import_before_import', 'get_not_for_sale_category_id', 10 );
```

It's only called now on Import by an admin and not every page load by every user.